# Принципы объектно-ориентированного программирования

Tags: ооп, java

Уважаемые граждане! Прошу вас помочь мне понять как пишется программное обеспечения в стиле ООП. Я читал про ООП, но толком не доходит, как правильно делать, может я не то читаю или просто не доходит, например:

Допустим необходимо создать (или уже есть) программу расчёта\учёта каких то данных (например продажа автомобилей TOYOTA), есть три машины Corolla, Camry, Carina. Мне нужно поднять цену Camry и Corolla а Carina сделать дешевле и посчитать количество оставшихся машин.

**Можно ли сделать так (Java)**:
Создаю три класса Corolla, Camry, Carina - в этих классах описываю машины (их номер, модель, цену, количество) потом создаю класс Control с методом **main** в этом методе создаю объекты этих классов и через них меняю цену машинам в этом же классе создаю статический метод который посчитает мне количество машин. - все классы в одном пакете.
 - Эта программа будет соответствовать объектной ориентированности, я всё правильно понял или вообще всё не так и делать так нельзя, я просто не могу понять как правильно подходить к задачи и её решать. Может у вас есть правильный код и вы мне его покажите или может что-то умное подскажите почитать...
 - **PS**: Задачу придумал на ходу просто чтобы показать на примере! Спасибо, люди ...

Comment: все правильно..

Comment: только лучше сделать сначала родительский класс "машина" и наследовать его тремя другими 

"статический метод который посчитает мне количество машин" тут непонятно, как-то нехорошо из класса обращаться к экземплярам. лучше создать класс автосалона и в свойства его экземпляра добавлять экземпляр машины, конкретного  класса, вывести метод который будет считать машины по заданным параметрам.

Comment: Когда же перестанут давать этот мертворожденный пример с машинами. Что реально кто-то так описывает классы?

Comment: @Alexey_Ku, Вы на правильном пути. 

Действительно, попытка использовать методологию решения *сложных* (оперирующих множеством эволюционирущих сущностей) задач (а именно, ООП) для написания примитивной программы часто ставит в тупик. 

Возникает естественный вопрос - "А нафига козе баян?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры машин одинаковые? Логика работы с разными моделями?
В общем абстрагируемся от продажи, представиим описание автомобиля с точки зрения устройства. Автомобиль может иметь признаки общие для всех автомобилей, иметь различные призаки (количество дверей), может иметь различную реализацию двигателя.

```
class Vehicles
{
  class Car
  {
     abstract class Engine;
  }
  class Camry : Car
  {
     class Engine
     {
       ...
     }
  }
}
```

Для начала можно создать класс Car и расширять его для конкретной марки. Но понимаете, все зависит от ваших задач. А вдруг вы мотоциклы начнете продавать? Можно создать класс с описаниями двигателей. Либо расширять Car в тип кузова. В общем вопросы ООП в таком контексте это больше вопрос осознания задачи, прогнозирования потребностей. Можно за год запрограммировать каждый винтик, что бы его было удобно продать, заменить и узнать в каких машинах он стоит, а можно создать по классу на машину и успокоится. Да и вообще попробуйте начать со структуры базы данных, а потом уже думать зачем вам ООП.